# How to stop Python's ElementTree XML parser from replacing html entities like `&#x0A`?

Tags: python-3.x, xml, xml.etree

In my xml data there are html hexadecimal entities like `&#x0A;`. In this case the ElementTree xml parser would convert them to `&#10;`.
It somehow looks like a bug to me, or is it a feature?
Is there a way to stop the parser from doing this?

**example.py**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_RFtree = ET.parse("input.xml")
xml_RFtree.write("output.xml")
```

**input.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Parameter Type="&#x0A;" />
```

**output.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Parameter Type="&#10;" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructs are 100% equivalent, and a parser isn't going to retain meaningless distinctions in your input. If you had spaces around the equals sign, it wouldn't retain those either: the distinctions are ignorable, so it's the job of a parser to get rid of them.

Incidentally, the parser is converting `&xa;` to a newline character, and the serializer is converting the newline character to `&#10;`. The assumption is that what your application wants to see as the attribute value in the element tree is a newline character.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer! I wasn't aware that decimal codes exists.